# psql:ERROR: syntax error at or near "ï»¿" LINE 1: ï»¿

Tags: bash, postgresql

Hi I have written this script to execute pgSQL function and I'm getting this error

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/NorthStar/Dhruva/server-specific-scripts/crons/ResetETA

db="Dhruva"
file="/home/NorthStar/Dhruva/server-specific-scripts/crons/ResetETA/query.sql"

cmd="psql -d $db -f $file"

su postgres -c "$cmd" >> reset.log 2> reset.log

if su postgres -c "$cmd"; then
    echo "ETA Reset successed" >> resset.log
else
    echo "ETA Reset faild" >> reset_error.log
fi
```

Comment: Looks like `resset.log` is a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a Unicode byte-order mark.

Use a text editor that saves plain utf-8 text without a byte-order mark, like notepad++, Sublime Text, gedit, vim/emacs, etc to write your scripts.

Don't write SQL, or any other programming-style code, with a word processor.

Comment: Don't recommend windows softwares on unix/linux :D :P

Comment: Thanks @Craig Ringer

Comment: @anishsane Eh. Didn't notice the tags. Few tools on Linux will write a BOM, especially by default, hence my assumption it was Windows. Amended.